# Header and footer alignment

Tags: header-footer

After typesetting, the page numbers in my document fluctuates from right aligned to centre aligned.  How can I ensure a specific and consistent page number alignment?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, final]{book}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate
%Original date format: \today \par
\cleanlookdateon% Remove ordinal day reference
%Modified date format: \today
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar,graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[translate=babel]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{paralist}
%\ChTitleUpperCase
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChNameVar{\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
%usepackage{tocloft}
%\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{color}\
%\usepackage{appendix}
%\autoref{app:...}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson}
%See MikTeX and Advanced LaTeX.pdf
%microtype is used for justification of paragraphs
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% scale dots
\newcommand\mydot[1]{\scalebox{#1}{.}}
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
  {\hbox{.}}
  {\hbox{\mydot{2}}}
  {}
  {}
% change separation between dots
\renewcommand\@dotsep{10} %default: 4.5
\makeatother
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
%\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{1pt}
%\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{1pt}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-.5ex}
\usepackage{lipsum} % placeholder text
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=pl,up]{caption}
```

Comment: In which consistent position do you desire the page numbering? By the way, since oneside is being used, the `E`, `O` modifiers for `fancyhdr` have no real effect.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you make a copy of your file, and strip the copy down to a *minimum* working example? Presumably not all of your packages are necessary to demonstrate the problem? :)

Comment: I usually place the page numbers at the bottom of the page and centre-align it. The text provided constitutes a minimum working example in my view as I intend to prepare a thesis.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Donavon change the line `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` to `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @Donavon I'm glad you got a solution but do note that this is **not** a Minimum Working Example. Next time, please post a truly minimal example. The fact that you intend to write a thesis is irrelevant. The example is to show the specific aspect of typesetting which your question is concerned with.

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMedina Do you want to join the »answer the unanswered« club? We could finally get this Q off the list.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hi. I just saw your message. I've provided an answer below, so this (I think) can be considered out of the non-answered list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

to

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```